# Disable input text access but keep the element enabled

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want to do something like this
[image]

The textbox can't be accesed but is enabled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `readonly` attribute.

```html
<input value="some value" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Or you can attach an event listener to the `input`'s `keypress`, `keydown`, `drop` and `dragover` `event`s and prevent the default action. You will also need to disable copying, cutting, and pasting by returning false. You may want to prevent the contextmenu event to prevent right clicking the input.

```html
<input id="testInput" value="some value" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false"/>
<script>
document.getElementById("testInput").addEventListener("keypress", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
document.getElementById("testInput").addEventListener("keydown", 
function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
});
document.getElementById("testInput").addEventListener("dragover", 
function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
});
document.getElementById("testInput").addEventListener("drop", 
function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
});
document.getElementById("testInput").addEventListener("contextmenu", 
function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

With jQuery:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="testInput" value="some value" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false"/>
 <script>
$('#testInput').on("keypress keydown dragover drop contextmenu",function(e){
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Santiago No problem.

Comment: You can still drag-and-drop text inside the `<input>` to change its value. You can check all possible modifications with the `input` event alone, but unfortunately it isn’t cancelable.

Comment: @Xufox I added preventing of `dragover` event.

Comment: @hev1 You also need to prevent `drop`. Then it’ll work.

Answer (score 0):

That is not textbox. Google made looks like textbox and binding data through JavaScript. You could also do the same by creating a textbox like a box and bind the data to it with [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Comment: but how can i set the "cursor" position to the text lenght? i alredy tried that

Comment: You can use the `direction: ltr;` in your style for the box element.